# Hybrid approach in metabolomics (NMR and MS)

Tags: mass-spectrometry

Is it currently common in metabolomics to combine two quantification methods, namely NMR (nuclear magnetic resonance) and MS (mass spectrometry, either liquid or gas)? If so, what would be profits from such an approach? Is it a promising direction or people are going to stay with a simple approach and they will be sticking to either of these two?

Comment: Hi and welcome, perhaps you could explain whats yuor investigation?

Comment: Hi Michael, I am just curious if running an NMR experiment will boost the insights that I may obtain from pure MS experiment. I have the feasibility to run both of them, I am just wondering if it makes sense.

Comment: It strikes me as more of a wet-lab question than bioinformatics, but its just my opinion

Comment: Not necessarily, wet-lab question would be, for instance, about applicability of a given method to the samples that I have. But I know the pros and cons of both methods. What is of my concern is the next step - whether the analysis utilizing both of these brings something more to the table in comparison with sole MS / NMR.